# Is it appropriate to ask for feedback for website design?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking because I just finished a new site design, and currently have nobody to ask who is knowledgeable in the subject, and would like to hear feedback from people I don't know.

It's more on design than functionality, which is why I though to ask here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant section from the [Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is "I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ...", then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is "I would like others to
>   explain ... to me", then you are probably OK.
>
> (Discussions are of course welcome in our [real time web chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).)

I cannot imagine too many ways that feedback solicitations could fit within these guidelines, however, you are welcome to ask if you feel otherwise.

Please consider other channels for any extended discussion of your site's design (as mentioned in the FAQ, chat is an appropriate channel for discussion and you should be able to search up at least a handful of webmaster forums which offer designers a place to review each others' work).